# The complex series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda e^{it})^n}{n!}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda e^{it})^n}{n!}=e^{\lambda e^{it}}$  fundamentally?
From the complex Taylor series expansion, this holds obviously. But by the following perspective, how to prove it right?
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda e^{it})^n}{n!}$$$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n}\cdot(\cos t+i\sin t)^{n}}{n!}$$$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n}\cos nt+i\cdot\lambda^{n}\sin nt}{n!}$$$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n}\cos nt}{n!}+i\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n}\sin nt}{n!} .$$

$$e^{\lambda e^{it}}=e^{\lambda\cos t+i\cdot\lambda\sin t}=e^{\lambda\cos t}\cdot e^{i\cdot\lambda\sin t}=e^{\lambda\cos t}\cdot(\cos(\lambda\sin t)+i\cdot  \sin(\lambda\sin t)).$$
Is $$e^{\lambda\cos t}\cdot(\cos(\lambda\sin t))=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n}\cos nt}{n!};$$$$e^{\lambda\cos t}\cdot(\sin(\lambda\sin t))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n}\sin nt}{n!}?$$

Comment: What is *your* definition of $e^z$? One of them is precisely $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$

Comment: @AnneBauval 
I define $e^{a+ib}:=e^a\cdot e^{ib}=e^a\cdot(\cos b+i\sin b).$

Comment: I think you can probably do this by checking that they both satisfy the ODE $y'(t)=\lambda i e^{it} y(t)$, and invoking uniqueness of solutions

Comment: this requires that you already know $e^\lambda=\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$ for $\lambda$ real

Comment: @Albert it's a way to approaching that,but not fundamentally.

Comment: what do you mean by not fundamentally? for me, $\exp$ is fundamentally the unique solution of the ODE $y'=y$ with initial condition $y(0)=1$

Comment: Elisa, What are *your* definitions of $e^a,\cos b,\sin b$?

Comment: @Albert I am sorry to say that  I have little knowledge about ODE. I want to solve it  technically by fundamental real analysis.

Comment: @AnneBauval May we define those as following?  $$e^{x}:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}.$$ 
$$\sin x:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1},\quad x\in \mathbb{R}.$$
$$\cos x=(\sin x)^{'}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1} \right )^{'}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}x^{2k},\quad x\in \mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: If so, you easily deduce $e^{ib}=\sum_{q=0}^\infty\frac{(ib)^q}{q!}$ and then $e^{a+ib}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{p,q\ge0\atop p+q=n}\frac{a^p(ib)^q}{p!q!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a+ib)^n}{n!}$ and we are done.

Comment: @AnneBauval I tried like this, but gave up halfway. I thought it's not  concise .Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Persevere, it should be concise.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes,indeed.I got it .Thanks a lot!